# How do I add a column and modify its data?

Tags: sql, sqlite

My table:

| Income | Expenses |
| --- | --- |
| 100 | 20 |
| 70 | 30 |
| 500 | 160 |

How do I add a column named `savings` that only has positive values?

| Income | Expenses | Savings |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 20 | 80 |
| 70 | 30 | 40 |
| 500 | 160 | 340 |
| 100 | 150 | - |

I tried:

```
MODIFY TABLE table_name
 ADD COLUNN column_def (income - expenses);
```

Comment: You will need to explain a bit more. Should this further column just added to the result of a query or really be another column of your table? Should this column only be filled once when adding it for the already present data? Or do you expect a column that is always automatically be filled by a trigger or similar? If so, what should be the purpose? We can just put the calculation in a query, no need to add a further column for that.

Answer (score 1):

Just experiment with this:
ALTER TABLE my_table ADD COLUMN new_column VARCHAR(255);
UPDATE my_table SET new_column = 'New Value' WHERE some_condition;

Answer (score 0):

To add a new column named "Savings" to your existing table and populate it with the appropriate values, you can use SQL's **ALTER TABLE** statement to add the column, and then use a **CASE** statement to calculate the savings based on the existing "Income" and "Expenses" columns.
Here's how you can do it

```
-- Add a new column named "Savings"    
ALTER TABLE your_table_name ADD COLUMN Savings INT;

-- Update the "Savings" column with the calculated values
UPDATE your_table_name
SET Savings = Income - Expenses;

-- Set negative "Savings" values to 0 (only keep positive values)
UPDATE your_table_name
SET Savings = 0
WHERE Savings < 0;
```

**Check Result** : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bba63d2/1/0
**Explanation**: These SQL statements will first add a new column named "Savings" to your table. Then, it will update the "Savings" column by subtracting the "Expenses" from the "Income" for each row. Finally, it will set any negative "Savings" values to 0, so only positive values remain in the "Savings" column.

Comment: No need to execute two separate update commands. We can do this in one step with ...WHERE income - expenses > 0. Furthermore, according to the description in the question, savings should be NULL rather than 0 in case the result is negative.

Answer (score -1):

Using [VIRTUAL column](https://www.sqlite.org/gencol.html) containing [CASE expression](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#the_case_expression):

```
ALTER TABLE
    table_name
ADD COLUMN
    Savings INTEGER AS (
        CASE
            WHEN (Income - Expenses) > 0 THEN
                Income - Expenses
            ELSE
                NULL
        END
    )
;
```